# How to test the result of an eventhandler

Tags: c#, delegates, nunit, moq

I have a ViewModel that receives an Interface with an Eventhandler in the constructor:

```
public VehiclesViewModel(IVehicles vehicles)
{
    _vehicles = vehicles;
    VehicleRows = new ObservableCollection<VehicleRowViewModel>();
    _vehicles.ListVehicles("secret", callback);
}
```

The callback adds all the listed vehicles into an ObservableCollection:

```
private void callback(object sender, MyAsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result is Vehicle[] vehicles)
    {
        foreach (var vehicle in vehicles)
        {
            VehicleRows.Add(new VehicleRowViewModel {Name = vehicle.Name});
        }
    }
}
public ObservableCollection<VehicleRowViewModel> VehicleRows { get; set; }
```

Vehicle and VehicleRowViewModels are just simple classes:

```
public class VehicleRowViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is the rest of the code:

```
public interface IVehicles
{
    void ListVehicles(string category, MyAsyncCompletedEventHandler callback);
}

public delegate void MyAsyncCompletedEventHandler(object sender, MyAsyncCompletedEventArgs e);

public class MyAsyncCompletedEventArgs : AsyncCompletedEventArgs
{
    public MyAsyncCompletedEventArgs(Exception ex) : base(ex, true, null)
    {
    }

    public object Result { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to test that the number of vehicles get added to the VehicleRows correctly:

```
[TestFixture]
public class VehiclesViewModelTests
{
    [Test]
    public void AllVehiclesFromCallBackEndUpInProperty()
    {
        var vehiclesMock = new Mock<IVehicles>();
        vehiclesMock.Setup(x => x.ListVehicles(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<MyAsyncCompletedEventHandler>())).Callback<string, MyAsyncCompletedEventHandler>(
            (s, c) =>
            {
                c = (sender, args) =>
                    args.Result = new List<Vehicle>
                    {
                        new Vehicle {Name = "TR3B"},
                        new Vehicle {Name = "Aurora"},
                        new Vehicle {Name = "HAUC"}
                    }.ToArray();
            });
        var testee = new VehiclesViewModel(vehiclesMock.Object);
        Assert.AreEqual(3,testee.VehicleRows.Count);
    }
}
```

But the test fails. How can I simulate the callback to test the ViewModel correctly?

I have a github repo with the sample: https://github.com/tbremeyer/TestEventHandler.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example test you are trying to define the delegate in the mocked callback when you should be invoking the delegate that was passed into the mocked callback.

Review the following refactor of your provided test that captures the callback, invokes it, and verifies the expected behavior

```
[Test]
public void AllVehiclesFromCallBackEndUpInProperty() {
    //Arrange
    MyAsyncCompletedEventHandler handler = null;

    var vehiclesMock = new Mock<IVehicles>();
    vehiclesMock
        .Setup(_ => _.ListVehicles(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<MyAsyncCompletedEventHandler>()))
        .Callback<string, MyAsyncCompletedEventHandler>((secret, callback) => {
            //capture the delegate for later use;
            handler = callback;
        });

    var subjectUnderTest = new VehiclesViewModel(vehiclesMock.Object);
    //check to make sure the hanler as been set at this point
    Assert.IsNotNull(handler);

    var vehicles = new List<Vehicle> {
        new Vehicle {Name = "TR3B"},
        new Vehicle {Name = "Aurora"},
        new Vehicle {Name = "HAUC"}
    }.ToArray();
    int expected = vehicles.Length;
    var eventArgs = new MyAsyncCompletedEventArgs(null) {
        Result = vehicles
    };

    //Act (invoke the delegate)
    handler.Invoke(vehiclesMock.Object, eventArgs);

    //Assert
    int actual = subjectUnderTest.VehicleRows.Count;
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

This test better represents the actual behavior of the subject under test.